# How to use BeautifulSoup to scrape

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

The aim of the script is to visit a website, that then generates a list of links for all the products using selenium through get_attribute.

Using requests, I visit each of these newly generated links to visit each product. Then I attempt to scrape using BeautifulSoup storing in different characteristic variables.

My issue is I believe that some of the products that I am trying to scrape does not have the category I am trying to scrape for, however, I believe most of them do. Is there a way to return something like "N/A" for products that don't have the stored characteristic I am scraping?

Here is my code:

```
import time
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

all_product = []

url = "https://www.vatainc.com/infusion.html?limit=all"
service = service.Service('/Users/Jonathan/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
service.start()
capabilities = {'chrome.binary': '/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'}
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, capabilities)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
links = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'product-name')]/a")]

for link in links:
    html = requests.get(link).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    products = soup.findAll("html")

    for product in products:
        name = product.find("div", {"class": "product-name"}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
        manufacturing_SKU = product.find("span", {"class": "i-sku"}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
        manufacturer = product.find("p", {"class": "manufacturer"}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
        description = product.find("div", {"class": "std description"}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
        included_products = product.find("div", {"class": "included_parts"}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
        price = product.find("span", {"class": "price"}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
        all_product.append([name, manufacturing_SKU, manufacturer, description, included_products, price])
print(all_product)
```

Here is my error code:

```
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-36feec64789d> in <module>()
     34         manufacturer = product.find("p", {"class": "manufacturer"}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
     35         description = product.find("div", {"class": "std description"}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
---> 36         included_products = product.find("div", {"class": "included_parts"}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
     37         price = product.find("span", {"class": "price"}).text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
     38         all_product.append([name, manufacturing_SKU, manufacturer, description, included_products, label, price])

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find()` method on your `BeautifulSoup` object is returning `None` when it can't find a DOM element that matches your query. Specifically, on that `included_products` line, it can't find a `div` with class `included_parts`.

You can do something like this to get an `included_products` value of `None` in this case:

```
def find_with_class(soup, tag_type, class_name):
    elements = soup.find(tag_type, {'class': class_name})
    if elements:
        return elements.text.strip('\n\r\t": ')
    else:
        return None

included_products = find_with_class(product, 'div', 'included_parts')
```